# Machine learning library to recognize words from noisy audio file

Tags: java, machine-learning, sox

We have been trying to recognize words from noisy audio files, I have googled a lot, used a bunch of APIs to split words from noisy, and also tried SOX, which is somewhat accurate (80% of the words are split correctly), right now i need to recognize these words, I have tried google speech api calling it from Java, but it's not as accurate as I hoped, because of some remaining noises.

We have been trying audio comparison, as we have a list of wave files with words in a dictionary, the comparison is done through MusicG library, but it is not working as expected.

Lately I have been thinking about some machine learning algorithm where i can teach the program, for example the audio "Dog" is the string "dog" and then repeat it until the program recognizes it automatically.

Is there any good/known library that can handle that with audio files?
If so, what would be the best approach to teach ? the bytes of the audio file? wave length?

Also, if you know some other way to do what I expect, please, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider looking into Hidden Markov Models in conjunction with training from a set of audio files.  The HMM approach models transition probabilities among symbols. You may tune the number of states that are "remembered" in the decision process.

As part of the analysis you would need to consider the time warp aspect - i.e. intra-symbol pause will differ among the training and the matched audios.

@Evan Knowles has added that MFCC's are the standard way to create HMM-ready symbols from speech.

Comment: He'll need symbols too - MFCCs are the standard way to transform speech into something HMM-suitable.